# iOS app crashing on Testflight

Tags: ios, crash, testflight

My application working fine on development environment but when I submit the same to test flight for beta testing it is crashing on few devices/iOS(no specific pattern)

Working fine on below devices without any crashes :

```
iPhone 7 (iOS 10.0.1)(Binary size 58.9 MB)
iPhone 7+ (iOS 10.2)(Binary size 75.8 MB)
iPhone 6 (iOS 9.3.1)(Binary size 58.8 MB)
iPhone 6 (iOS 10.1)(Binary size 58.8 MB)
iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4)(Binary size 211 MB)
iPhone 5 (iOS 8.3)(Binary size 211 MB)
```

Crashing on below devices:

```
iPhone 6+ (iOS 9.0.2)(Binary size 75.8 MB)
iPhone 6s (iOS 9.0.)(Binary size 58.8 MB)
iPhone 6 (~iOS 9.1.X.)(~58 MB)
```

Points to note:

```
Objective C code base(no swift)
Enabled bitcode 
No PNGs(Using PDF vector)
Deployment target 8.2...base SDK 10.2
Optimization level:- Fastest,Smallest
Done profiling in release mode with zombie enabled and found no issues
```

Comment: No one can help if you don't provide relevant details about the crash and associated code.

Comment: Thanks for reply.... Crashes are random e.g.         CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"xxxCell"] ;

Comment: @Abhishek post your crash log.